# Deserialize JSON to dictionary using LINQ to JSON

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have some JSON like this (serializes from a dictionary):

```
{
  "Context":
  {
    "Test": "Test"
  }
}
```

And would like to use JSON.NET's JSON to LINQ to deserialize it into a dictionary.

I've tried something different things:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
obj.Value<Dictionary<string, string>>("Context");
```

But this throws an exception like this:

> System.InvalidCastException
>   Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken

I've have also tried:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var context = obj.Values("Context");
```

But then I can't figure out how to process the elements into a dictionary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
string json = "{\"Context\":{\"Test\": \"Test\"}}";
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var dict = obj["Context"].ToObject<Dictionary<string,string>>();
```

Comment: You should us the ToObject<T> method on JToken instead.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've edited the answer to reflect that.